# How to register custom drupal module to drush?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drush

There is custom module available on drupal.org. I need to provide the drush install command so one can install/download the module from terminal.

For example : I have test module on Drupal.org.

I need to provide `drush dl test` as well as `drush en test -y`.

Please help me.

Comment: If you have a drupal.org project page it should be able to find it.

Answer (score 2):

If your custom module is already on drupal.org you would have an url similar to https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg where, in this instance, `wysiwyg` would be your project name. As you correctly stated, and continuing with the `wysiwyg` example, the command `drush dl wysiwyg && drush en wysiwyg -y` will download and enable the module.

Comment: just `drush en wysiwyg -y` will also download it if it needs to.

Comment: Thanks! I actually didn't know that.

Comment: just doubled your productivity :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to post your module on drupal.org as a project , it will give to you an url like https://www.drupal.org/project/mymodule

`drush` use drupal.org to download release of your choice about module , theme etc..

Also , if you have already your module into your code you can directly enable it

```
drush en mymodule -y
```

If you want to cloud it , you can use github and download it from it everywhere you want , make release etc..